# How to add folder to StorageLibrary without RequestAddFolderAsync in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, sd-card

I need to save app files to plugged SD card. I'm using UWP and Windows 10.
MSDN tells how [to do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries) with Windows Libraries.

```
var myPicsLibrary = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
await myPicsLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync();
```

`RequestAddFolderAsync()` shows file picker, where user can choose folder to add into Pictures. In my case it's a folder, created on SD card.

Is there a way to do this thing without file picker dialog?

I'm trying to do [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card):

```
var myPicsLibrary = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);

// Get the logical root folder for all external storage devices.
StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;

// Get the first child folder, which represents the SD card.
StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

var folder = await sdCard.CreateFolderAsync("MySDCardFolder");

myPicsLibrary.Folders.Insert(myDocs.Folders.Count+1, folder); // NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
myPicsLibrary.Folders.Add(folder); // NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
```

Or maybe I can do the same without using Windows Libraries directly working with `SDCard`?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

In the another hand my question sounds like "How to save files to plugged SD card?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StorageLibrary.Folders` gets the folders in the current library, it return the `IObservableVector` of the `StorageFolder`. When we add the folder into the `IObservableVector`, it will not change the folder in files system. It will throw the "The method or operation is not implemented." exception.

We should be able to get the name of the folder, and create the folder uses that name. Then we can [`StorageFile.CopyAsync`](http://CopyAsync) method to copy the file that in your folder.

For example:

```
public static async Task CopyFolderAsync(StorageFolder source, StorageFolder destinationContainer, string desiredName = null)
{
    StorageFolder destinationFolder = null;
    destinationFolder = await destinationContainer.CreateFolderAsync(
        desiredName ?? source.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    foreach (var file in await source.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        await file.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
    foreach (var folder in await source.GetFoldersAsync())
    {
        await CopyFolderAsync(folder, destinationFolder);
    }
}
```

Then we can use the `CopyFolderAsync` method to copy the folder in the Picture Library.

```
var myPicsLibrary = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
var myfolder = myPicsLibrary.Folders[0];
StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
var folder = await sdCard.CreateFolderAsync("MySDCardFolder");
await CopyFolderAsync(folder, myfolder);
```

Comment: I heed to copy **TO** SD card, not **FROM**. Or create and save files on SD card directly. It thows `Access denied` if i try to create file on SD like `SDCard.CreateFileAsync("testpdf.pdf");` or  `await file.CopyAsync(to, from);`, that's why i trying to use Windows Libraries. And I added StorageDevice permission in app manifest

Comment: In the another hand my question sounds like "How to save files to plugged SD card?"

Comment: @ashchuk You should be able to add the File Type Associations in Declarations in Package.appxmanifest. Please refer the [following question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3db59292-8abb-4bfd-a46e-926ad78239f9/wp81-getfoldersasync-access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: This helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I get from your question you need to create a Folder in PicturesLibrary . 
You can use the code below to add a folder into PicturesLibrary

```
await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("MySDCardFolder");
```

if you want to make it on SD Card only Maybe `KnownFolders.RemovableDevices` Should be helpful . I didn't used `KnownFolders.RemovableDevices` yet but if you have any issue let me know to test it on my phone directly

Comment: `await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("MySDCardFolder");` creates folder in Pictures folder, it's ok there. But
`await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.CreateFolderAsync("TESTFOLDER"); // COMException` not worked